# Android Camera API With Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, camera

In Android , I want to use navigation drawer with camera api (not using the intent , only camera api)on full screen texture view without loosing the picture quality taken by camera Help me

Comment: Share your code/workaround/attempt first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in using Camera API and enable the system Camera like functionality, you are first required to get a Preview. A preview can be obtained through your own custom implementation like this,

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;
private static final String TAG = "CAMERA_PREVIEW";
private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;
public boolean isSafeToTakePicture = false;

public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
    // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
        // preview surface does not exist
        return;
    }

    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        isSafeToTakePicture = false;
    } catch (Exception e){
        // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }

    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
    // reformatting changes here

    // start preview with new settings
    try {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);

        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        isSafeToTakePicture = true;

    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetRatio=(double)h / w;

    if (sizes == null) return null;

    Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    int targetHeight = h;

    for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
        if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
        }
    }

    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
    }
    return optimalSize;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
    final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

    if(mCamera != null) {
        List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }
    }
}
```

}

This code actually scales the preview in accordance with your screen dimensions, something that doesn't happen inherently in the API.

In your Activity where you are to use the camera, you can just go ahead and start the preview like this,

```
Camera mCamera = getCameraInstance();

    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);
```

Once you have obtained the preview, you can invoke the API functionality to capture images and videos as required.

[This](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.java) too is a good demo to start with.

Comment: Thanxx Aneeb but what about the navigation drawer , I am able to set up the camera but navigation drawer is creating some problem .......Do help me in that too...........

Comment: This [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/) is a decent tutorial on setting up material nav drawers. Please have a look.